# How to add a package from a local source?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, package, .net-core

I'm trying to build a C# console application using Visual Studio Code but when I try to install packages the application uses wrong local folder with as a **local source.**

I have **dotnet** installed in my C program files, I think the program will be solved if I can use my dotnet folder as a local source but I don't know how to do it.

---

I tried these commands in terminal :

`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

---

and I get this error:

```
MovieAPP>dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Writing C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpB0AD.tmp info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' into project 'E:\courses\C-Sharp\MovieAPP\MovieAPP.csproj'. log : Restoring packages for E:\courses\C-Sharp\MovieAPP\MovieAPP.csproj...

Writing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpACF8.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' into project 'E:\courses\C-Sharp\MovieAPP\MovieAPP.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for E:\courses\C-Sharp\MovieAPP\MovieAPP.csproj...
```

***error***: The local source 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Compressed\WebMatrixExtensionsGallery' doesn't exist.

Comment: Why don't you try adding the packages with NuGet..?

Comment: MovieAPP>dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json
  Writing C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA220.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Newtonsoft.Json' into project 'E:\courses\C-Sharp\MovieAPP\MovieAPP.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for E:\courses\C-Sharp\MovieAPP\MovieAPP.csproj...

error: The local source 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Compressed\WebMatrixExtensionsGallery' doesn't exist.